# Android: Rejecting Invocation

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have built an app for android which takes the data and enters it in a google sheet.
The form has like 600+ values and was working flawlessly but it has broken upon adding more fields and now I am being greeted with these in logs when it crashes:

```
2020-02-05 21:22:07.139 13879-13879/? E/ngpatternsurve: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-02-05 21:22:15.218 13879-13879/com.example.farmingpatternsurvey E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.farmingpatternsurvey, PID: 13879
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.example.farmingpatternsurvey.AddItem: void com.example.farmingpatternsurvey.AddItem.addItemToSheet() failed to verify: void com.example.farmingpatternsurvey.AddItem.addItemToSheet(): [0x1901] Rejecting invocation, expected 70 argument registers, method signature has 71 or more (declaration of 'com.example.farmingpatternsurvey.AddItem' appears in /data/app/com.example.farmingpatternsurvey-QW7Re8Z-Ysdw_hc1wHuYTA==/base.apk)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

App crashes when I try to start this 'AddItem' activity from my 'MainActivity' activity using this simple code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==buttonAddItem){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddItem.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Here is the method addItemToSheet() from AddItem activity:

```
 private void   addItemToSheet() {
final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Adding Item","Please wait");
        final String farmer_name = editfarmer_name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String husband_father = edithusband_father.getText().toString().trim();
        final String village = editvillage.getText().toString().trim();
        .  
        .
        .
        .
        .(more 'fetching strings from editText and storing in variable')

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xyxyyxyxyxyx/exec",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,"Error, Please try again, no internet or weak internet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        ) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                //here we pass params
                params.put("action","addItem");
                params.put("farmer_name",farmer_name);
                params.put("husband_father",husband_father);
                params.put("village",village);
                .
                .
                .
                .
                . (more params)

}
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. Tried googling but it has not helped.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Somewhere in there you have a method that it thinks should take 70 parameters but its being passed 71 (or vice versa).  Do a build clean, and try a full uninstall on the device-  this sounds like a stale compiled java file somewhere.

Comment: .. or something went wrong while dynamically replacing changed code parts (-> Instant Run). My advice is the same Gabe already gave to you: uninstall the app, perform a clean build and then reinstall the app.

Comment: @GabeSechan and Robert

Thanks for help guys.
 I have already tried reinstalling app on several devices and have also cleaned the build several times as well.
Also, I am already passing like 200+ params and the app is working fine but when I add more params, this crash happens and if 70 is the number of params the function is expecting, app should have crashed way to early but it did not.

Thanks

Comment: If you're passing 200+ params into a function, you need to refactor.  That's not a maintainable implementation

Comment: @GabeSechan I am sorry, I am not passing 200 parameters in a function, I am adding 200 (key, value) pairs and adding them in a hashmap.

Please take a look at params.put lines

Thank you :)

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere-  that's passing a single hashmap.  The problem is somewhere you're passing 70 parameters as parameters.  Or you just have a totally corrupt compiled java file somewhere.

Comment: @IshankGupta Have you resolved the issue and how? I have a similar issue.

Comment: @Codist No, I did not manage to solve it